# How to Reproduce an Ink-Type Sketch with Latex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, includegraphics, inkscape, sketch

Consider, for example, the Wikiquote photo

[image]

from https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Yogi_Berra

which, with Inkscape, I was able to produce

[image]

QUESTION: Is it possible, and if so, how may I reproduce the Ink sketch in Latex?

Motivation for this question---Being able to use a Latex-generated image instead of an Inkscape-png would allow, for example, the use of such images in future posts that would be accessible by everyone. Although most of the time, I suspect, the actual image in not important, there are questions (e.g., pertaining say to images incorporating transparencies) in which an actual image in the post will serve better than say, an `example-image`.

I would be most grateful to any user who posts an answer to this question in which the actual steps are outlined in generating the Latex-code for the Inkscape image.

Thank you.

Comment: If you can achieve this with a command line call to `inkscape`, then you should be able to call the command line from LaTeX. It is almost impossible to do this without the help of external software.

Comment: I don't really understand what's the purpose of this...? Just include the png and includegraphics it. Worst case post the base64 of the image if external link dies.